# Choosing the columns of the reduced column form of the matrix as the basis elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying this tutorial problem [Finding the basis and its dimension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqXOYgpbMBM), I am trying to understand why she has not taken the first three columns of the reduced matrix as its basis elements rather she took the first three columns(that is the corresponding columns of the reduced matrix) as the basis elements as can be seen at slot 7:15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are interested in a basis of the column space. Row operations does not preserve the column space.

As an example, $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0  & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has its RREF being $R_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ span different space.

Another example is , $A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1  & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ has its RREF being $R_2=\begin{bmatrix}1  & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ span different space.

It is known that the pivot columns spans the column space. Hence, she took the corresponding column in the original matrix.

Edit:

The column space of $A_1$ can be described as $\operatorname{Span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}=\operatorname{Span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

The column space of $R_1$ can be described as $\operatorname{Span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}=\operatorname{Span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Comment: How can we prove the assertion that Row operations do not preserve the column space?

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: those countere examples are proofs tht row operations do not preserve the column space. recall that the reduced row echelon formed can be obtained by elementary operations from the original matrix and I have shown that the original matrix and its RREF do not share the same column space.

Comment: okay @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: Hm,..but why you took in your both examples, the first column of $A$ and the first column of its RREF?@SiongThyeGoh

Comment: I just take a basis of the column space, the second column in the first example is zero so i can't take that, for the second example, the two columns of $A$ are identical, I just pick one of them. Similar for its RREF.

Comment: I see, but why are spanning the first column of the matrix  "AND" the first column of RREF? what can we conclude by spanning the two columns of different matrices?

Comment: the original question is why she didn't take the columns of the reduced matrix right? the column space of the original matrix and the column space of the reduced matrix are no longer the same.

Comment: I see, thank you!